# Regarding sign of energy stored in springs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, conventions, spring

A block of mass $m$ is at natural length initially.It is attached to two springs having spring constant $k1$ and $k2$. It is attached in such a way that when one elongates ,the other compresses.Using work energy theorem , I need to find the velocity of the block at half the amplitude of release of the block. Spring stores energy as $0.5kx^2$. The sign is decided if the force by spring is opposing displacement($-ve$) or along displacement($+ve$).
Is this concept also applied in *Work-energy* equation where initial system energy is equal to final energy system?

Comment: Energy is a scalar quantity. It has no sign

Comment: So does it mean we take the mod of energy in each object in system for initial and final energy in Work-Energy conservation equation?

Comment: The change in kinetic energy can be positive or negative but the value of kinetic energy has no sign

Comment: Kinetic energy depends on v squared. It is always positive. Spring energy is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The change in kinetic energy of a system has sign.

Whereas change in potential energy of a system solely depends on reference.